# CSS border-spacing for every other row

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I am targeting Chrome and other CSS3 compliant browsers and would like to have border separation for every other row.
The CSS I currently have working for every row looks like this-

```
table{
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing: 0px 3px;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

What I would like to achieve is this:

**CSS**

```
table{
  border-collapse:separate;
}
table tr:nth-of-type(odd){
  border-spacing: 0px 3px;      
}
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a-one</td><td>a-two</td><td>a-three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>a-four</td><td>a-five</td><td>a-six</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b-one</td><td>b-two</td><td>b-three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>b-four</td><td>b-five</td><td>b-six</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c-one</td><td>c-two</td><td>c-three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>c-four</td><td>c-five</td><td>c-six</td>
    </tr>       
</table>
```

The data is in two row sets and needs to be connected, whereas different sets need to be separated.  I would like to keep it in table form to take advantage of the browsers auto-column widths.  It seems like border-spacing can only be achieved on the table level.  I am already using borders for styling so transparent borders is not a viable option.
Any chance for me- or I am I stuck?
JS-fiddle here identical to above here: http://jsfiddle.net/sSba4/

Comment: Can we see your table HTML? Or better yet, build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us to look at. You may also want to apply border styles so we can see what it looks like (or what you want it to look like).

Comment: added html and jsFiddle link. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd argue that if the data needs to be visually chunked in separate containers, perhaps the most semantic solution would involve using multiple tables.

However, if you want to keep everything in a single table for whatever reason, then you would need to introduce non-semantic markup to create those visual separations, as `border-spacing` is a property of the table, not of the row or cell.

```
<table>
    <tr><th></th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apples</td>
        <td>$3.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Oranges</td>
        <td>$2.46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><th></th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pears</td>
        <td>$2.10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apples</td>
        <td>$3.50</td>
    <tr><th></th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Oranges</td>
        <td>$2.46</td>
    <tr>

        <td>Pears</td>
        <td>$2.10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

table tr td {
  border: solid #ccc 1px;
  padding: 5px 7px;
}

table tr th {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

See it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/wYCNg/

Comment: I was hoping that the most semantic solution would be to use multiple `<tbody>` elements in a table, since the data sets are all related to one another. I haven't been able to find a way to apply margins or border spacing to table bodies, though...

Comment: Ah, forgot about tbody, yes, that would be the most semantic solution.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to stick with tables to ensure consistent column widths across sets based on column content.  I was hoping to not introduce empty rows but I guess I have no choice unless there is another way to ensure consistent column widths based on content (not fixed or %) outside of tables.

Answer (score 4):

How about adding an additional row with transparent borders?

html:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>a-one</td><td>a-two</td><td>a-three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a-four</td><td>a-five</td><td>a-six</td></tr>
    <tr class="break"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>b-one</td><td>b-two</td><td>b-three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>b-four</td><td>b-five</td><td>b-six</td></tr>
    <tr class="break"><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>c-one</td><td>c-two</td><td>c-three</td></tr>
    <tr><td>c-four</td><td>c-five</td><td>c-six</td></tr>  
</table>
```

css:

```
table{
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
tr.break, tr.break td{
    border:none;
    height:5px;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: Essentially the same answer as Duopixel's

Comment: well, yes. I was writing it at the same time, I did not realise there was an answer already when I posted it.

Answer (score 1):

I've just been considering the same matter. If you put div element inside td, you can use plenty of box-model properties, eg. margin. If you additionally hide td borders you can use margin to set space between cells, rows, cols.

```css
#tab {
 border-collapse:collapse;
}

#tab td{
 padding:0px;
}

#tab td>div {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 background-color:#97FFF8;
 margin:1px;
}

#tab td:nth-child(1)>div {
 margin-right:10px;
}

#tab tr:nth-child(1) div {
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tab">
 <tbody>    
  <tr>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```